# Reactjs routes show the loading spinner in all cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

In my small application I have some routes and when I change path appropriate component is loaded. But Issue is -  I have loading spinner in my ProductsPage container, I wait for response from db and while it's pending I show spinner and when I change route to the Basket it showing infinite spinner but I don't have spinner in Basket component

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <Route path="/" exact component={MainPage}/>
                <Route path="/:category" component={ProductsPage}/>
                <Route path="/basket" component={Basket}/>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and here is my products component

```
render() {
    let products;
    let description = null;

    if (this.state.categorizedItems && this.state.productsDescription) {
        products = (
            <div className={classes.Products}>
                {
                    this.state.categorizedItems.map(item => (
                        <Product
                            addedProduct={this.addProductHandler}
                            key={item.id}
                            title={item.title}
                            backgroundImage={item.backgroundLink}
                        />
                    ))
                }
                <ItemsAlignment/>
            </div>
        );
        description = (
            <div className={classes.Description}>
                {this.state.productsDescription}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        products = (<><Spinner/></>)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.ProductsWrapper}>
                <span className={classes.ProductsTitle}>
                    {this.state.productsTitle}
                </span>
                <>
                    {description}
                    {products}
                </>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Probably more information needed, can you please share the `<ProductsPage />` component as well? Also how you are adding `<Router />` and `<Switch />` components in your code.

Comment: Swap the routes, the /:category with /basket, and it should work fine. Put the line with the basket before the :category. And as @norbitrial said , wrap them into a <Switch>.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to turn off the spinner after the response from your server came And before changing route into the "Basket"